In LEAN4 prover, what's the problem of generalising a type from String to a free type?
I'd like to convert the following code in Coq to Lean 4:
(this is the beginning of the soundness proof of type system F-)
Set Implicit Arguments.
Require Import LibLN.
Implicit Types x : var.
Implicit Types X : var.

(* ********************************************************************** *)
(** * Description of the Language *)

(** Representation of pre-types *)

Inductive typ : Set :=
  | typ_top   : typ
  | typ_bvar  : nat -> typ
  | typ_fvar  : var -> typ
  | typ_arrow : typ -> typ -> typ
  | typ_all   : typ -> typ -> typ.

(** Representation of pre-terms *)

Inductive trm : Set :=
  | trm_bvar : nat -> trm
  | trm_fvar : var -> trm
  | trm_abs  : typ -> trm -> trm
  | trm_app  : trm -> trm -> trm
  | trm_tabs : typ -> trm -> trm
  | trm_tapp : trm -> typ -> trm.

initially the following definition compiles successfully:

section FSubStr

  /- Representation of pre-types -/
  inductive Typ : Type where
    | typ_top   : Typ
    | typ_bvar  : Nat → Typ
    | typ_fvar  : String → Typ
    | typ_arrow : Typ → Typ → Typ
    | typ_all   : Typ → Typ → Typ

  /- Representation of pre-terms -/
  inductive Trm : Type where
    | trm_bvar : Nat → Trm
    | trm_fvar : String → Trm
    | trm_abs  : Typ → Trm → Trm
    | trm_app  : Trm → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tabs : Typ → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tapp : Trm → Typ → Trm

end FSubStr

but I'm not satisfy with the non-DeBruijn type declaration typ_fvar  : String → Typ and want it to be more flexible, so I introduced a free type Var to make it consistent with the old proof:

section FSub

  variable (Var : Type)

  /- We use section variables to represent both term and type variables -/

  -- variable (x : Var) -- For term variables
  -- variable (X : Var) -- For type variables

  /- Description of the Language -/

  /- Representation of pre-types -/
  inductive Typ : Type where
    | typ_top   : Typ
    | typ_bvar  : Nat → Typ
    | typ_fvar  : Var → Typ
    | typ_arrow : Typ → Typ → Typ
    | typ_all   : Typ → Typ → Typ

  /- Representation of pre-terms -/
  inductive Trm : Type where
    | trm_bvar : Nat → Trm
    | trm_fvar : Var → Trm
    | trm_abs  : Typ → Trm → Trm
    | trm_app  : Trm → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tabs : Typ → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tapp : Trm → Typ → Trm

end FSub


this broke the compilation:
FSub.lean:25:17
type expected, got
  (Typ : Type → Type)

How did this happen and what can be done to fix it? I tried to add a universe layer on top of it but got the same error.

First, I highly recommend using vs code for Lean.  It will underline the exact part which is wrong, which in your case is the Typ in trm_abs  : Typ → Trm → Trm.  Also, you are hurting yourself by making Var a variable.  I think what is going on is that it is auto-implicating Var as a  parameter to Typ which you can see if you do #check Typ

yeah Lean4 plugin in VSCode (windsurf) is exactly what I'm using. Also good idea, is there a way to disable this auto-implicating? Or I have to define this entire block in a function?

Sorry, spoke too soon.  It is not auto implicit in this case.  Variables work differently in Lean verse in Coq.  All they do is add that variable to as a parameter to everything which uses that variable.  But it is still the same issue.  If you want Var as a variable to Typ then you need to apply it also to uses of Typ even in the section.  (Like (Typ Var) -> Trm -> Trm.)

Or better yet, make Var explicit in the signature of your two inductives.

that will be very verbose, I have thousands of inductions like this :D Is there a way to aggregate them as a preamble?

if this doesn't work, I'll just fallback to defining a custom Var struct

In Lean, variables are light-weight (unlike a similar mechanism in Coq).  All they do is automatically fill in parameters to declarations which use them.  In this case it adds (Var : Type) as a parameter to both Typ and Trm.  You can see this with #print Typ or #check Typ.  In all later uses of Trm and Typ (even if still in the section) you have to supply this parameter.  So the definition for Trm would become:
  inductive Trm : Type where
    | trm_bvar : Nat → Trm
    | trm_fvar : Var → Trm
    | trm_abs  : (Typ Var) → Trm → Trm
    | trm_app  : Trm → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tabs : (Typ Var) → Trm → Trm
    | trm_tapp : Trm → (Typ Var) → Trm

You are still saving a lot of typing by not having to supply the variable for Trm
In the definition of Trm. I can’t think of a way to avoid having to add Var like above (short of replacing the variable with a concrete type like a structure).  But even if you have thousands of these (as you say in the comments), I don’t think it would be that hard to type and you could probably use find and replace to good advantage.

verified to be working, but there should be a shorter way of declaring it
